# Finding the values in an array that are between 2 specified values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I have an array of floats and 2 input variable:

```
var test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6];
var low = 0.7;
var high = 3.2;
```

Basically, I want to get a new array that has all the values from test_array that are great than or equal to my low value and less than or equal to my high value. I'd rather avoid something like this:

```js
var test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6];
var low = 0.7;
var high = 3.2;
var new_array = [];

for (let i=0; i<test_array.length; i++) {
    if (test_array[i] >= low && test_array[i] <= high) {
        new_array.push(test_array[i]);
    }
}
console.log(new_array.sort());
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this with a few lines rather than the `for loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve the result.

```js
var test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6];
var low = 0.7;
var high = 3.2;
var new_array = [];

new_array = test_array.filter(e => e >= low && e <= high);
console.log(new_array.sort());
```

Comment: Both answers were excellent. I'm still trying to get a handle on using filter in arrays. Bonus points for sorting ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6];
var low = 0.7;
var high = 3.2;

let answers = test_array.filter(n => {
  return n >= low && n <= high
});
console.log(answers);
```